# Checkboxes in IF statements is there an assumption?

Tags: apex

In the following statement Booking__c is a checkbox.  Is the assumption this field is 'true'?

```java
if(itinerary.Booking__c && itinerary.Close_Date__c < mayEight &&
    assignment.ItineraryItem__r.Total_Price__c != 0) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All checkbox fields in the databases are with type Boolean in apex and you can treat them as such. Yes your assumption is right.

"itinerary.Booking__c" and "itinerary.Booking__c == true" are the same thing when used in IF evaluation.